# Passing checked items in a list view to an arraylist/array

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Hey I'm new to android app development and in this situation I'm creating a mobile application which stores data in SQLite database and show it in a list view and the items in the list can be checked by check boxes.

In here I want to get the position of the checked items so I can pass them to the database, and when the application opens again previously checked items will be already checked. I want to save the position when the button is clicked.

I've used a SparseBooleanArray to store the checked items but I've no idea to pass the values of SparseBooleanArray to DB and I'm stuck there.
Help me with this and thanks in advance.

*

```
public class Subscribe extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView lanList;
    DatabaseHelper translateDB;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String clicked;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscribe);
        translateDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        lanList = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.subscribeBtn);



        showLang();

    }



    public void showLang(){
        final Cursor cursor = translateDB.retriveLang();
        System.out.println("1");
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(Subscribe.this, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("2");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            list.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,list);

        lanList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lanList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        lanList.setItemChecked(1,true);     <--- used this to check the functioning 

        lanList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                clicked = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Toast.makeText(Subscribe.this,"You selected '"+ clicked+"' " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SparseBooleanArray checkedItems =lanList.getCheckedItemPositions();
                System.out.println("1 - " +checkedItems);




                if (checkedItems != null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++) {
                        if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
                            String item = lanList.getAdapter().getItem(
                                    checkedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
                            System.out.println("2 - " +item);
                            translateDB.subscribedLang(item);
                        }   
                    }       
                }



            }
        });

    }
```

*

SO what I'm planning to do is pass the checked positions to db and get the positions and lanList.setItemChecked(x,true); and pass position values to this code.

Help me with this.